# What database manager should i use

Tags: java

What database manager should i use for open source, which i can use with java IDE? I want to fetch tables easily. And i can manipulate date as well as required. It will be great help if someone give me a free open source database manager then i can start my first project.

```
public class DbConn {
final static String databaseName = "DB1";
final static String userName = "root";
final static String password = "root";
final static String server = "localhost";
final String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":1526/" + databaseName;
Connection conn;
public void dbconn() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, userName, password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database not Connected \n" + e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I have completed my java program but as i created my database in college so i could not bring that database home, so i need a database manager so that i can complete my task

Comment: You are currently using MySQL, so no reason not to stick with that - it's free (download it from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mySQL or SQLyog. I use SQLyog. This is a silly question according to the mark of stackOVERFLOW. But i can understand that you come here to know, not for scoring points.
I will always be there for you, so keep trying...
Best of Luck.
Link >> http://sqlyog.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Thanks @sudipta.dey i got to know many of the little things from your posts, which are understandable for me now.